# Is this index for SELECT DISTINCT ON wrong? Why the Seq Scan is still in plans?

Tags: postgresql, distinct-on

I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.player (
    company_id character varying NOT NULL,
    id character varying NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    family character varying,
    start_from timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    surrogate_key character varying NOT NULL
);
```

I'm trying to implement a [SCD (Slowly Changing Dimension) Type 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row).

So if I try this query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON ( surrogate_key ) surrogate_key, * FROM player ORDER BY surrogate_key, created_at DESC;
```

it works. But the explain analyze is:

```sql
Unique  (cost=10.47..10.99 rows=101 width=171) (actual time=0.098..0.115 rows=101 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=10.47..10.73 rows=103 width=171) (actual time=0.097..0.100 rows=103 loops=1)
        Sort Key: surrogate_key, created_at DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 46kB
        ->  Seq Scan on player  (cost=0.00..7.03 rows=103 width=171) (actual time=0.013..0.039 rows=103 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.076 ms
Execution Time: 0.135 ms
```

So I created an index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON player (surrogate_key, created_at DESC);
```

but the explain analyze is the same:

```sql
Unique  (cost=10.47..10.99 rows=101 width=171) (actual time=0.105..0.122 rows=101 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=10.47..10.73 rows=103 width=171) (actual time=0.104..0.107 rows=103 loops=1)
        Sort Key: surrogate_key, created_at DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 46kB
        ->  Seq Scan on player  (cost=0.00..7.03 rows=103 width=171) (actual time=0.010..0.045 rows=103 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.081 ms
Execution Time: 0.139 ms
```

Is it possible? Am I doing index wrong?

I expect that there is no longer the seq scan with the index. Am I wrong?

Comment: For such a tiny table a Seq Scan will always be the fastest way. If you want see the effect of the index you will need much more rows.

Comment: I tried with 1 million.

Comment: Not with the plans in your question.

Comment: What do you mean? Anyway I tried it now and it works, you're right. I was wrong in my test with 1 million. The explain analyze is now:

Comment: `Unique  (cost=0.42..18014.26 rows=99984 width=145) (actual time=0.019..63.597 rows=100001 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using player_surrogate_key_created_at_idx on player  (cost=0.42..17764.26 rows=100003 width=145) (actual time=0.018..35.547 rows=100003 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.091 ms
Execution Time: 65.696 ms`

Comment: It works with 100 000 too. But is there a way to speed up more?